# Finding Kernel of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

> Let T:R3→R2 be the linear transformation defined by
>
> T(x,y,z)=(x−y−2z,2x−2z)
>
> Then Ker(T) is a line in R3, written parametrically as
>
> r(t)=t(a,b,c) for some (a,b,c)∈R3
>
> (a,b,c) =  . . .
>
> (Write your answer as a vector (a,b,c). For example "(2,3,4)")

So, when I tried to solve the question making **x-y-2z = 0,** and **2x-2z= 0** I got the answer **x(1,1,-2)** but it seems that it's incorrect. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: If you show your own work, then someone can point out your exact error instead of offering some perhaps unrelated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $x=z$ gives $y=-z$ and we obtain $$\ker(T)=\{t(1,-1,1)|t\in\mathbb R\}.$$